# Given a trigger in PostgreSQL how to determine it's relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to remove triggers from my database that were installed by a rails gem.

I've removed the tables like rr_admin_reports but the trigger is still there "rr_admin_reports":

I'm trying to delete the trigger like so:

```
DROP TRIGGER rr_admin_reports ON admin_reports;
```

But get the error:

```
ERROR:  trigger "rr_admin_reports" for table "admin_reports" does not exist
```

Is there a PostgreSQL console command I can run to learn where the trigger lives so I know what to enter after the ON?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query shows all the trigger names and their associated tables:

```
SELECT tgname,relname from pg_trigger JOIN pg_class c on tgrelid=c.oid;
```